# How to convert Sine to Cosine?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have some trigonometric quantities, which may be expressed in either sine or cosine, e.g., `ia = Cos[wt]`, `ib = -Sin[π/6 + wt]`, `ic = -Sin[π/6 - wt]`. In order to compare the phase of the three quantities, I would like to convert all quantities to the form of `Cos[wt + phase]`. For the three quantities, they need to appear as `ia = Cos[wt]`, `ib = Cos[wt - 2π/3]`, `ic = Cos[wt + 2π/3]` after the manipulation. What is a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Inactivate[{Cos[wt], -Sin[π/6 + wt], -Sin[π/6 - wt]} //.
  {Sin[x_] -> Cos[x-π/2], Cos[-wt+x_] -> Cos[wt-x], -Cos[x_] -> Cos[x+π]}, Cos]
```

> {Inactive[Cos][wt], Inactive[Cos][2π/3 + wt], Inactive[Cos][-2π/3 + wt]}

The `Inactivate[..., Cos]` wrapper makes sure that the `Cos[...]` functions do not automatically revert to `Sin[...]` etc. by instantaneous simplification. You can use `Activate` on the result to return it to its normal state:

```
Activate[%]
```

> {Cos[wt], -Sin[π/6 + wt], -Sin[π/6 - wt]}

Comment: Thank you. Like the `ReplaceRepeated //.` idea.